# What do these instructions when cloning a GitHub repo mean?

Tags: reactjs, json, git, github, package.json

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRJHg.png)

For context, this a ReactJS project for a chrome extension for desktops. I'm just not entirely sure why I would have to change the name of these fields in the package.json.

The next instructions are to npm install the dependencies and then npm start the project and I understand those. It's the first two I don't understand.

I'm new to git cloning repositories so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Rather than a screenshot with no context, could you include a link to where you saw this, and the instructions as actual text.

Comment: I signed an NDA this code is not open source. The most I can show is that. I gave context, what else can I say?

Comment: Maybe you should ask the maintainers of the proprietary software, then - it's very hard to answer a "why" question about something we can't even see. Maybe there are restrictions on distributing it under the original brand, so they want you to rename any derivative works; maybe they just left those instructions in place by mistake. Either way, you can still at least paste text as text, rather than a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The fields in package.json are just meta informations on your package.
If you would like to publish your project or even build it. The values from this file are used.

Comment: I understand that but why do I need to change them?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).